# How to hide input for X and Y axis in plotly.js?

Tags: plotly

Is it posible to hide or disable the input field which appears when clicking the axis in plotly.js?

[plotly.js line chart](https://plot.ly/javascript/line-charts/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no setting in Plotly but you could hide the editable `div` in your css settings.

Setting the `layout` of `xaxis` to `fixedrange: true` will hide the input box but won't allow any kind of zooming.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```css
div.editable {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```